# this.Controls.Add() visibility = false

Tags: c#

When Programmatically adding a Label during runtime in C#, the Label's visibility gets changed to false after "this.Controls.Add(whatever), which is not true.  Any idea how to get around this?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Label label = new Label();
        label.Location = new Point(15, 15);
        label.Text = "Test";
        label.AutoSize = true;
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(label.Visible));
        this.Controls.Add(label);
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(label.Visible));
    }
}
```

The first MessageBox displays "true", while the second MessageBox displays "false"

Comment: Is the container that you're adding the label to not visible?

Comment: That is accurate.  The label is not yet visible, that happens later when you can actually see the window.

Answer (score 4):

You're adding the label to a form that hasn't been shown (yet), so of course since the entire form isn't visible, the label on that form isn't visible either.

When the form is shown, the label will become visible.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I'm not sure why it's initially true.

Comment: @DavePerich Presumably without a parent the developers felt that there'd be no sensible reason to check is visibility.

Comment: @Servy Do you know of a way around this? I need to check the visibility of a Label in order to know what to set other Labels' (that are also programmatically added during runtime) visibilities to.

Comment: @DavePerich Yes, as I [already told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771452/this-controls-add-visibility-false/25771499?noredirect=1#comment40303146_25771596), if it's important that the label's visibility be true, you should *make sure that the label is actually visible*.  Trying to figure out how to get a label to say that it's visible when it's not actually visible is the wrong approach to take.  Well, either that or don't inspect the labels visibility if that's not what you actually want to know.

Comment: Sorry about that repeat, I sent the other message before I recieved your answer

Comment: That's interesting and makes sense. I wouldn't have even caught this but I was trying to verify that my controls are set to visible in a unit test. In my unit test I called the Show() method on the form before calling my method that sets the visibilities. Now they're true. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Because its not added yet, it defaults to true, then you add it and it gets the value from the parent

Comment: The reason why I need the visibility is to use it as a condition for a method.  How do I get the correct visibility value?

Comment: @DavePerich Make sure that the label *is actually visible* if its important that it's `Visible` property return `true`.

Comment: Don't use visibility, subclass it and add your own member variable to track in your application if it should be shownn or not